# Filling the missing elements in Python after using groupby

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, pandas-groupby, missing-data

I am working on a case for machine learning detecting fraud in transactions. I am grouping people and their fraud ratio in the each transaction. I am using their emails because it defines the people. There are 160k rows in the sheet. When I group them like this:

`data['ratebymail']=pd.DataFrame(data.groupby('EMAIL')['ISFRAUD'].mean())`

There are two problems. The data['ratebymail'] returns NaN for each email. The second problem is the data is 90k rows. Each email has 1 value but in original set, it should be 160k with duplicates. For the second occurrence in the dataset I should assign the same fraud ratio to that person in another transaction. The order is important as well, therefore I cannot append it.

```
i = 0
ratebymail = []
for mail in data['EMAIL']:
    for other_mail in other_mails:
        if mail == other_mail:
        ratebymail[i] = ratios[j]
    i += 1
```

I tried something like this but I am so confused that I couldn't finish the code. I am desperate for help. Thank you!

Edit: Typing error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure to have well understood your problem, but I think you want to get the mean of fraud ratio for each email. In this case, the answer is:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(111)
# create data
data = pd.DataFrame([np.random.randint(0,100,size=1000), np.random.rand(1000)], index=['EMAIL', 'ISFRAUD']).T
# aggregate
rateByEmail = data.groupby('EMAIL').mean()
rateByEmail.head()
```

Out:

```
EMAIL   ISFRAUD
0.0     0.466479
1.0     0.615915
10.0    0.665675
11.0    0.462092
12.0    0.315427
```

Please give an example of your input and the desired output if it is not the answer to your question.

Comment: Thank you for your response. There is no need to generate a random dataset. I have already quite a lot. Those are my data: Index(['BASKETPAIDPRICE', 'BASKETINSTALLMENT', 'BASKETPAYMENTCHANNEL',
       'BASKETPAYMENTSOURCETYPE', 'BASKETISTHREEDS', 'BASKETREGISTERCARD',
       'BASKETHASVIRTUALITEM', 'CARDTYPE', 'CARDASSOCIATION', 'EMAIL',
       'CARDBANKID', 'MERCHANT_ID', 'ISFRAUD'],
      dtype='object')
I have EMAIL data which are 160k row. After grouping they are reduced to 90k data. That means every data occurs once. But in original set there may be more than one. So they ...

Comment: So in the original data set there will be a new column which corresponds with the emails since it indicates a person. The order will stay the same. That data will enter to the DecisionTreeRegressor to model it and I hope it will increase the accuracy.

Comment: https://ibb.co/DC1Wgj7 in this excel sheet you can see that red colored column is gonna be created by python.